# Python - Splitting strings in a list delimited by space

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list in the following format:

```
mylist = ["a word 1 2 3 4","b word 5 6 7 8"]
```

I'm trying to split this into 2 new lists, one for each string, ie.:

```
newlist1 = ["a","word","1","2","3","4"]
newlist2 = ["b","word","5","6","7","8"]
```

but I've not had any luck. I've tried various methods and looked at lots of similar questions but haven't been able to apply those successfully to my issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm still very new to Python and I know this is probably a very simple thing to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to split the *two* strings in the list and bind the result to *two* variables you can simply do this:

```
mylist = ["a word 1 2 3 4","b word 5 6 7 8"]  

newlist1 = mylist[0].split()
newlist2 = mylist[1].split()
```

This is OK for 2 variables but in general, if you had more strings to split, that quickly becomes unwieldy. For a more general solution you can simply use a list of lists:

```
>>> newlists = [s.split() for s in mylist]
>>> newlists
[['a', 'word', '1', '2', '3', '4'], ['b', 'word', '5', '6', '7', '8']]
```

Then access each list by index:

```
>>> newlists[0]
['a', 'word', '1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> newlists[1]
['b', 'word', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

Or you might use a dictionary:

```
>>> d = {'newlist{}'.format(i) : s.split() for i, s in enumerate(mylist, 1)}
>>> d
{'newlist1': ['a', 'word', '1', '2', '3', '4'], 'newlist2': ['b', 'word', '5', '6', '7', '8']}
```

Now you can access the list by key:

```
>>> d['newlist1']
['a', 'word', '1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> d['newlist2']
['b', 'word', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

Comment: Thanks for such an in-depth response! You're right, the generic solution is much more useful and worked like a charm, especially since I might not specifically always have 2 lists. The only thing is, how would I then access the elements of the lists in newlists? eg. '2'?

Comment: `newlists[1]` accesses the second list. `newlists[2]` would give you the third list if there was 3 or more. Accessing the elements of the nested lists, e.g. `newlists[0][3]` would give the fourth element of the first list, in your example that would be the string `'2'`.

Comment: Ok, so if I was accessing specifically '2' in the first list, would I use `newlists[0][3]`? edit: brilliant, that's worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @user193369: that's right. And for completeness if you used the dictionary option it would be `d['newlist1'][3]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.split()`

**Ex**:

```
mylist = ["a word 1 2 3 4","b word 5 6 7 8"]
for i in mylist:
    print(i.split())
```

**Output** :

```
['a', 'word', '1', '2', '3', '4']
['b', 'word', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

**Using list comprehension** :

```
print([i.split() for i in mylist])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way

```
splitSentences = [ sent.split(" ") for sent in mylist]
```

> [['a', 'word', '1', '2', '3', '4'], ['b', 'word', '5', '6', '7', '8']]